# Python : Sorting first column with associated two others columns

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have a file with indexes on the first columns which are written randomly. I have for each one of these indexes 2 others values corresponding to the second columns and third columns.

For example, I have a file `'file.dat'` like this :

```
2 0.9 1.0
1 0.5 2.6
10 11.2 3.1
87 32.1 8.2
...
...
100 1.2 9.8
103 0.7 0.6
```

The only way I found on SO is to do :

```
Photoz_tab = np.loadtxt('file.dat')
Photoz_tab = sorted(Photoz_tab, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[0])
```

This way, I can sort the first index while keeping their 2 others values associated.

But it seems there is maybe another solution (which actually  doesn't work):

```
Photoz_tab = np.loadtxt('file.dat')
idx = np.argsort(Photoz_tab[:,0])
Photoz_tab = Photoz_tab[idx,:,:]
```

But the second and third values is not conserved towards first sorted index.

So, my question is to know how to conserve this order :

a simple :

`Photoz_tab = Photoz_tab[idx,idx,idx]`is enough ? I am going to test now, I keep you informed.

**UPDATE 1:** the syntax `Photoz_tab = Photoz_tab[idx,:,:]` throws an error.

The fix is to do instead:

`Photoz_tab = Photoz_tab[idx][:][:]` and it seems to produce the wanted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using `pandas`, it is very easy to do it in `DataFrame`. The good thing of using this is that `DataFrame` index ensures that your data has unique index, otherwise it will throw an error. Plus, you'll have the advantage of easy data manipulation.

```
df = pd.read_csv("/root/to/folder/test.dat", index_col=0, header=None, sep=' ').sort_index()
```

Comment: This solution is prettty cool, mostly of the unique test, I will keep it in mind, Regards